# Delay pie chart animation until in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-plugins

I am using this jquery plugin by LugoLabs called "Circles" in order to animate a few pie charts on a website I am building. (https://github.com/lugolabs/circles)

It works perfectly, but the pie chart animation starts on page load and I want to delay it until it is seen by the viewer.

Would it be possible to use something like viewportchecker.js (https://github.com/dirkgroenen/jQuery-viewport-checker) to only start the animation once someone is viewing it? I've used this before on other projects with success, but I'm having a hard time integrating it with the existing javascript.

----Example setup---

HTML:

```
<div class="circle" id="circles-1"></div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
var myCircle = Circles.create({
id:           'circles-1',
radius:       60,
value:        43,
maxValue:     100,
width:        10,
text:         function(value){return value + '%';},
colors:       ['#D3B6C6', '#4B253A'],
duration:       400,
wrpClass:     'circles-wrp',
textClass:      'circles-text'
styleWrapper: true,
styleText:    true
});
```

Comment: In case you missed it - the circles github has an example for this: https://github.com/lugolabs/circles/blob/master/spec/viewport.html , complete with a function `elementInViewport()` , I've just added it as a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d5b4r5q1/

Comment: Thanks! I had tried that but couldn't get it to work for some reason. Will try again.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid questions, but how would you insert the above script into that javascript to make it work? It isn't running when I do what I think would make sense. Its in a slightly different format as it doesn't use increasing numerical variables to create the circles.

Comment: I've just updated the Fiddle with your circle, don't know if it should look like that: http://jsfiddle.net/2vz6zb13/  I've just added your code into the `createCircles`-function and added a `,` after `textClass: 'circles-text'` that misses in your settings.

Comment: That works great! Thanks! (if you submit as an answer I'll mark it)

Comment: Glad I was able to be of help and just submitted the info of the comments and the detail of the adjustment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously mentioned as comment: The [circles github](https://github.com/lugolabs/circles) has an example for starting the circles animation when the circle is in view: https://github.com/lugolabs/circles/blob/master/spec/viewport.html.
I've added a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5b4r5q1/) containing this example, and as there was the question how to adjust the circle from OP to work with this example I've adjusted this in another [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vz6zb13/). The only adjustment was to change the function `createCircles` as follows:

```
function createCircles() {
  var myCircle = Circles.create({
     id:           'circles-1',
     radius:       60,
     value:        43,
     maxValue:     100,
     width:        10,
     text:         function(value){return value + '%';},
     colors:       ['#D3B6C6', '#4B253A'],
     duration:     400,
     wrpClass:     'circles-wrp',
     textClass:    'circles-text',
     styleWrapper: true,
     styleText:    true
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just calculate the scroll height like:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $('#circles-1').offset().top + 810)
    {   
        $(function() {
         ///your pies, 810px is your height
        });

    });
    }
});
```

instead of loading a plugin...

Comment: It keeps re-loading the animation every time I scroll. What is causing that?